# Merge documents from 2 collections in MongoDB & overwrite properties on a field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections in MongoDB :

**Collection1 :**

```js
{
    _id:1,            
    Field1: "Some info",
    Field2: "Some other info",
    Elements: [
        {
            id: 0,
            Enabled: false
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            Enabled: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            Enabled: false
        }
    ]
 }
```

**Collection2 :**

```js
{
    Identifier: "identifier",
    ElementsOverride: [
        {
            id: 0,
            Enabled: true                    
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            Enabled: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            Enabled: true                    
        }
    ]
 }
```

What I would like to do is perform an operation which flattens "Element" collection and returns Collection1 with the flattened Element collection (basically the Enabled field from collection 2 overwrites the enabled field of Collection 1.

Is there a way to achieve this in Mongodb?

---

Adding more clarification for what the output should be like:
Essentially what I'm trying to do is merge the document identified by `_id:1` in collection 1 (document1), with the document identified by Identifier: "identifier" in collection 2 (document 2) such that:

- All the properties in document1 and document2 are available in the output.
- The ElementsOverride from document2 with the same ID's as document1 (ex; `id: 0`) will overwrite the values in document1

**Required Output :**

```
{
    _id:1,     
    Identifier: "identifier",       
    Field1: "Some info",
    Field2: "Some other info",
    Elements: [
        {
            id: 0,
            Enabled: true
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            Enabled: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            Enabled: true
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Does it have to be done on entire collection & what is your dataset size ?

Comment: @whoami: No, it is 2 specific documents (1 from each collection)

Comment: that's do-able but is there any relation between these two collections ? Like is there a primary key & foreign key to join these two collections docs into one doc ?

Comment: There is no primary key between the 2 documents. But the relation is that the "ElementsOverride" collection in Document2 has the same elements as the "Elements" collection in Document1. And the "id" property in the elements collection directly match up (id:0 in Document1.Elements and Document2.ElementsOverride).

Comment: If you've similar matching objects in `ElementsOverride` array for other documents in `ElementsOverride` collection then without any foreign key relationship between collections, it would not be possible to JOIN these two collections. So basically you can map `id`'s inside arrays but it would be possible if id's match to other document's `ElementsOverride` array in collection2 you'll not be able to join to specific 1-to-1 rather it would be 1-to-many. If you can say `id`'s in array are unique across documents in `ElementsOverride` then it would be possible

Comment: @whoami : The document1 from collection1 will be used to merge with a specific document2 (speicifed by Identifier) from collection2. I've updated the question in the hopes that I'm a little more clear. Please let me know if there are other details I can provide to help make it more clear. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
    /** get only one required doc from Collection1 */
    { $match: { _id: 1 } },
    /** Join relative doc from Collection2 */
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "Collection2",
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                            { $eq: ["$Identifier", "identifier"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "data"
        }
    },
    /** As lookup will default to an array of objects getting an object out of array */
    { $unwind: '$data' },
    /** Replacing existing elements field of Collection1 & adding Identifier field to existing doc */
    {
        $addFields: {
            Identifier: '$data.Identifier', Elements:
            {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $reverseArray: { $setUnion: ["$Elements", "$data.ElementsOverride"] } },
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", { $cond: [{ $in: ['$$this.id', '$$value.id'] }, [], ['$$this']] }] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    /** removing unnecessary field created at lookup stage */
    { $project: { data: 0 } }
])
```

**Test :**  [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RT_Y4W9Zw9s)

Comment: This worked off the bat! Thank you so much :) . Much appreciated.

Comment: What would I need to change if Collection1.Elements had additional properties that I needed to be retained? Right now, it overwrites the entire node. Once again, thanks and appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Sirpingalot : It wouldn't be that easy & can be tricky & How many additional properties does each obj have ?

Comment: They have quite a few each. Each item in the Elements collection has an additional 3-4 properties, some of which are arrays.

Comment: Any thoughts on it?

Comment: @Sirpingalot : I've tried a bit, but it's completely deviating from this query, I can try once more & will post my answer here :-)

Comment: @Sirpingalot : Try this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/IBOPUMIMsLm

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked :). You are amazing!

Comment: Do you believe doing something like this is inefficient to perform in mongodb vs performing this merging of documents in code behind ?

Comment: @Sirpingalot : Yes,Especially on you've huge dataset i.e; millions of docs.! MongoDB transactions are straight forward & can do basic manipulations,We would mostly do similar in code but using code is much efficient & elegant for your situation where you've more no.of constraints/requirements like above(One good thing here is after first stage `match` & `lookup` you're operating on only one doc till end), From above query you can do first 3 stages `match,lookup, unwind` & then thereafter it would be a bit easy to do rest in code as you'll need to operate on two arrays produced by above stages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights and your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want the output.

> flattens "Element" collection

generally means the array `Element` is *unwound*. Please correct my interpretation, in case I have misunderstood.

But, the following steps in Mongo Shell will get the result:

```
arr1 = db.c1.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$Elements" }, { $sort: { "Elements.id": 1 } ] ).toArray()
arr2 = db.c2.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$ElementsOverride" }, { $sort: { "ElementsOverride.id": 1 } ] ).toArray()

for (let i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    updated = Object.assign(arr1[i].Elements, arr2[i].ElementsOverride);
    arr1[i].Elements = updated
}
```

The variable `arr1` will have:

```
[
        {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Field1" : "Some info",
                "Field2" : "Some other info",
                "Elements" : {
                        "id" : 0,
                        "Enabled" : true
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Field1" : "Some info",
                "Field2" : "Some other info",
                "Elements" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "Enabled" : false
                }
        },
        {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Field1" : "Some info",
                "Field2" : "Some other info",
                "Elements" : {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "Enabled" : true
                }
        }
]
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ]

Updated to reflect the required output:

```
arr2 = db.c2.aggregate( [ 
                       { $unwind: "$ElementsOverride" }, 
                       { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$ElementsOverride" } }
] ).toArray()

db.c1.aggregate( [ 
{ $unwind: "$Elements" }, 
{ $addFields: { 
       "Elements.Enabled": {
           $filter: {
               input: arr2,
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.ElementsOverride.id", "$Elements.id" ] }
           }
       }
} },
{ $group: { 
       _id: "$_id", 
       doc: { $first: "$$ROOT"}, 
       Identifier: { $first: "$Elements.Enabled.Identifier"}, 
       Elements: { $push: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$Elements.Enabled", 0 ] } } 
} },
{ $addFields: { 
       "doc.Elements": "$Elements.ElementsOverride",  
       "doc.Identifier": { $arrayElemAt: [ "$Identifier", 0 ]  }
} },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } }
] )
```

[ EDIT ADD 2 ]

Here is another way of merging the documents:

```
doc1 = db.c1.findOne()
arr2 = db.c2.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$ElementsOverride" } ] ).toArray()

for (let e2 of arr2) {
  for (i = 0; i < doc1.Elements.length; i++) {
      if (doc1.Elements[i].id == e2.ElementsOverride.id) {
          doc1.Elements[i].Enabled = e2.ElementsOverride.Enabled
          doc1.Identifier = e2.Identifier
      }
  }
}
```

The output is the `doc1` document.

Comment: Updated the question since it was more than I was able to place in a comment.Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer with code to get the needed output. I made it a two step process to keep the code simple (and the process is for just one document only).

Comment: So, the first solution seems to be logical, but for some reason it is not updating the values when I run it (in Robo3T). 

The second query (Edit ADD), yielded no entries in the output collection

Again with the (Edit ADD2), the logic seems fairly straightforward, but the values don't seem to be updating. I'm going to check if it is something on my side